# Jquery loop compare not getting expected result

Tags: javascript, jquery

**This is my code. I will explain everything step by step :**

```
myobj ={ month: 1, total: 2 }{ month: 3, total: 1 }

newArray = [];
for(i=0;i<=5;i++){
   $.each(myobj.function(k,v){
   if(i==v.month){
     newArray.push(v.month)
   }else{
     newArray.push(0)
   }
})
}
```

After what I am getting is : 1,0,0,0,0,3,0,0,0,0

**expected output** : 1,0,3,0,0

I don't know what I am missing here. Can anyone please help me related this? I am stuck here

Comment: `myArray` is not an array in your snippet.

Comment: it is comming in object form..

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/tvba3eyg/ This logic does not work at all.  You need to make an [mcve] of your actual code

Comment: However, if this code actually worked over an array, yes you would be getting 10 values in the output array instead of just 5, because you have two month objects, and you are iterating 5 times.  You push either the month or 0 for each month.  So 2 months times 5 iterations = 10 values in the output array

Comment: @Taplar how can i get the expected values in expected way is there any example so i can go ahead ??

Comment: What is your purpose with this code?

Comment: Can you explain the logic of your code? I mean you have started loop from 0. So it will push 0 in your array. As you want 5 elements in your expected output, you should play with for loop which will run for 5 iterations

Comment: the thing is that what i actually want if its may then i want a array like in this way 
myArray = ['0','0','0','0','0'] //it will depends on the month 
if i ll have the myobj ={ month: 1, total: 2 }{ month: 3, total: 1 }
then i want myArray = ['1','0','3','0','0']

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your inner loop is pushing onto the new array for every item in the array, not just if the desired month is found.

Don't use an inner loop. Use `find()` to find the matching month, and push `0` if you don't find it.

```
for (i = 1; i <= 5; i++) {
    if (myobj.find(el => el.month == i)) {
        newArray.push(i);
    } else {
        newArray.push(0);
    }
}
```

if you want to push the totals instead of the months, assign the result of `find()` to a variable so you can get the total from it.

```
for (i = 1; i <= 5; i++) {
    var found = myobj.find(el => el.month == i);
    newArray.push(found ? found.total : 0);
}
```

Comment: one thing i want to confirm can we push total value in the same position ??

Comment: Sure. Assign the result of `find` to a variable, then push `variable.total`.

Comment: I am not getting your point now i am getting the same array what i actually want but i want the total value on this places..

Comment: If that's what you actually want, why do you push the month in your code? I updated the answer to show this.

Comment: thanx alot for helping me thanx again...